Push notifications on Android/Google TV using flutter
I created an app using flutter for Android/Google TV and I want to show notifications on the main TV screen when my app is in the background. When my app is in the foreground it works but in the background it does not show the push notification.
I can't find documentation to how to show notifications on Android/Google TV.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
